# callback setTimeout

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando una practica con funciones callback lo que quiero es que por cada vuelta que de el bucle exita un tiempo de espera de 2 segundos tengo un array con letras lo que intento hacer es que me imprima las letras del mismo cada 2 segundos.

Lo estoy tratando de hacer con el metodo setTimeout pero no obtengo el resultado esperado podrias brindarme un apoyo con este ejercicio por favor.

Saludos.

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function llamadora(array1,callback){

callback(array1);

}

var ejecutora = (function(array1){

array1.forEach(function(element) {

setTimeout(console.log(element),2000);

});

})

llamadora(array1, ejecutora)
```

Answer (score 1):

Te saludo y te propongo esta solución

```
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const imprime = () => {
 setInterval(function(){
   console.log(array1)
 }, 2000); 
}

imprime()
```

ACLARACIONES

> 1. No debes usar `setTimeOut()` ya que dicha instrucción solo se ejecutará una vez dado el tiempo que le establezcas
> 2. En su lugar una `setInterval()` que va a ejecutar el código asignado dentro del lapso de tiempo que tu le asignes de manera
>      indefinida
> 3. Solo modifique un poco la sintáxis usando una arrow function asignada a la constante imprime

ANEXO

Del mismo modo puedes con el método `map()` puedes recorrer el arreglo original y general una nuevo para entregar el arreglo como lo quieres mostrar, es decir imprimir los elementos cada 2 segundos; así mira:

```
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const imprime = () => {
 setInterval(() => {
   array1.map(ele => {
     console.log(ele)
   })
 }, 2000); 
}

imprime()
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda el segundo ejemplo se parece mucho a lo que quiero hacer voy a tratar de plasmarlo mas claramente.

Comment: por supuesto @JarviRangel espero te ayude

Comment: tengo un array con tres letras lo que quiero saber es si se puede hacer es que se recorra el array y me imprima la primera letra del mismo luego espere 2 segundos para imprimir el valor de la siguiente posición del array y asi sucesivamente hasta que se empriman todos los valores del array en la consola gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ok dame unos minutos @JarviRangel